# UTF-16 split in 2 chars

Tags: java, encoding, character-encoding, utf-16

I always believed that java uses `UTF-16` to encode its characters internally. This is confirmed by the fact that it uses `u+xxxx` format to represent character codes and the fact that it uses 16 bits to store a `char`.

**But sometimes `UTF-16` needs more than 2 bytes.** In that case java needs 2 `char` to represent 1 `UTF-16` character.

On a sidenote: This makes me wonder if it's more correct to say that *"java just supports the Unicode character set, and uses 16-bit cells to store characters"*.

**Question: Does the first `char` offer some method to determine that a second `char` is used, or that the 2 belong together?**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, UTF-16 was invented when Unicode expanded pass the 65536 code point limit of Unicode 1.0 to the 1114112 code point limit it has today.

This allows it to support the entire Universal Character Set while maintaining compatibility with UCS-2; the obsolete encoding of all Unicode characters as two-byte units that is obsolete precisely because it cannot encode all Unicode characters in Unicode 2.0 or later.

> Does the first char offer some method to determine that a second char is used, or that the 2 belong together?

Yes, in UTF-16, a two-byte unit is either:

1. A high surrogate, which must always be followed by a low surrogate. Between `0xD800` and `0xDBFF` inclusive, `isHighSurrogate` will return `true`.
2. A low surrogate that must always follow a high surrogate.  Between `0xDC00` and `0xDFFF` inclusive, `isLowSurrogate` will return `true`.
3. A non-surrogate.

Non-surrogate map directly with a BMP character of the same code point.

Surrogates combine to represent astral plane characters:

1. Subtract 0x010000 from the code point.
2. Add the top 10 bits to 0xD800 to get the high surrogate.
3. Add the lower 10 bits to 0xDC00 to get the low surrogate.

In Java you can do this by first checking `isBmpCodePoint` on an `int` with the codepoint. If that is true then you can just cast it to `char` to get the single UTF-16 unit that encodes it. Otherwise you can call `highSurrogate` to get the first `char` and `lowSurrogate` to get the second.

As well as `isBmpCodePoint` you could use `charCount` which returns `1` for BMP characters and `2` if you need surrogates. This is useful if you are going to create an array of either `1` or `2` characters to hold the value.

Since the surrogate code points are never assigned characters, this means the encoding is unambiguous for the entire Universal Character Set.

It's also self correcting, a mistake in the stream can be isolated rather than leading to all further characters being misread. E.g. If we find an isolated low surrogate we know that bit is wrong but can still read the rest of the stream.

Some full examples, but I'm not too hot in Java (Unicode on the other hand, I know well, and that's the knowledge I used to answer this), so if someone spots a n00b Java error but thinks I got the Unicode-knowledge part correct please just go ahead and edit this post accordingly:

`""` is a string with a single Unicode character, `U+10300` which is a letter from the Old Italic Alphabet. For the most part, these "Astral Planes" characters as they're semi-jokingly called are relatively obscure as the Unicode Consortium try to be as useful as they can without going outside the easier-to-use BMP (Basic Multilingual Plane; `U+0000` to `U+FFFF`, though sometimes listed as "`U+0000` to `U+FFFD` as `U+FFFE` and `U+FFFF` are both non-characters and shouldn't be used in most cases).

(If you're experimenting with this, then those that use  directly will depend on how well your text editor copes with it).

If you examine `"".length` you'll get `2` because `length` gives you the number of UTF-16 encoding units, not the number of characters.

`new StringBuilder().appendCodePoint(0x10300).toString() == ""` should return `true`.

`Character.charCount(0x10300)` will return `2` as we need two UTF-16 `char` to encode it. `Character.isBmpCodePoint(0x10300)` will return `false`.

`Character.codePointAt("", 0)` will return `66304` which is `0x10300`, because when it sees a high surrogate it includes reading the following low surrogate in the calculation.

`Character.highSurrogate(0x10300) == 0xD800 && Character.lowSurrogate(0x10300) == 0xDF00` is true, as those are the high and low surrogates the character should be split into to encode in UTF-16.

Likewise `"".charAt(0) == 0xD800 && "".charAt(1) == 0xDF00` because `charAt` deals with UTF-16 units, not Unicode characters.

By the same token `"" == "\uD800\uDF00"` which uses escapes for the two surrogates.

Comment: I think the asker meant the java primitive type char rather than a UTF-16 surrogate. In which case no, there is no concept of linking 2 chars together. Such characters cannot be stored in a java primitive char.

Comment: Actually you are right - even the String implementation for characters above U+FFFF is backed by pairs of char.

Comment: Thanks, so I guess `Character.isHighSurrogate(char)` can be used to verify whether it belongs together with the next `char`.

Comment: Yep. I'll add a little on that.

Comment: Could you give an example of how surrogates combine to represent astral plane characters ? I guess you are refering to characters like ♥

Comment: No, `♥` is U+2665, so it's in the BMP and only needs one `char`. I'll give a full example with `` which is a single Unicode character, but needs two `char` to represent in Java because it's two UTF-16 units.

Comment: @user1886323 yes, that's what UTF-16 means. I'm not too hot on Java, but I know my Unicode encodings well :)